# Deploy functions to Cloud Functions using Python

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-api-python-client

Is there a way to deploy scripts from a repository as GitHub to Cloud Functions with python without using docker or subprocess commands?

I tried this [sample code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/main/packages/google-cloud-functions/samples/generated_samples/cloudfunctions_v2_generated_function_service_create_function_sync.py) that uses the [CreateFunctionRequest](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudfunctions/latest/google.cloud.functions_v2.types.CreateFunctionRequest) method for deploying a function to CF, but there is no explanation on how defining the function itself.

Digging in the documentation I found that I need to specify a [Function](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudfunctions/latest/google.cloud.functions_v2.types.Function) type and pass it as parameter for that method above.

The `Function` class has an attribute that defines the build config of the function. That attribute `build_config` is used to fetch the source code of the function.

However, it seems like the [BuildConfig](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudfunctions/latest/google.cloud.functions_v2.types.BuildConfig) type only accepts deployment using docker, nothing like uploading a source code from GCS to CF as we have in `gcloud` [commands](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploy?hl=pt-br#from-cloud-storage).

Comment: Please check this documentation on [deploying from Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploy#from-cloud-storage) and [deploying from a source repository](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploy#from-source-repo). When you deploy your source code to Cloud Functions, it will be stored to Cloud Storage and will be built to a container image and it will be pushed to an image registry. Please check [build process](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/building) for your reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting as an answer from my previous comment:

Please check this documentation on [deploying from Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploy#from-cloud-storage) and [deploying from a source repository](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploy#from-source-repo). When you deploy your source code to Cloud Functions, it will be stored to Cloud Storage and will be built to a container image and it will be pushed to an image registry. Please check [build process](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/building) for your reference.